# Change OS Name from email send by exim

Tags: freebsd, exim, mta

OS: FREEBSD 9

OS ROLE: SERVER

MAIL SERVER: EXIM

When I send mail from my freebsd server to gmail. and when i click on show original. I shows my os name too along with mta name. as in first line of following quote.

```
Received: from root by myprivateserver.org with local (Exim 4.80.1 (FreeBSD))
    (envelope-from )
    id 1WL5v6-0000XL-3E
    for nishananand@gmail.com; Wed, 05 Mar 2014 07:07:12 +0000
To: nishananand@gmail.com
Subject: hello
Message-Id: 
From: Charlie Root 
Date: Wed, 05 Mar 2014 07:07:12 +0000
```

My question is this that can I hide the the freebsd from

```
(Exim 4.80.1 (FreeBSD))
```

Or can htis line be customized at least.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of the `Received:` header are set by the Exim option `received_header_text`.  You can strip out the Exim and OS versions by setting it to

```
received_header_text = Received: \
  ${if def:sender_rcvhost {from $sender_rcvhost\n\t}\
  {${if def:sender_ident \
  {from ${quote_local_part:$sender_ident} }}\
  ${if def:sender_helo_name {(helo=$sender_helo_name)\n\t}}}}\
  by $primary_hostname \
  ${if def:received_protocol {with $received_protocol}} \
  ${if def:tls_cipher {($tls_cipher)\n\t}}\
  ${if def:sender_address \
  {(envelope-from <$sender_address>)\n\t}}\
  id $message_exim_id\
  ${if def:received_for {\n\tfor $received_for}}
```

I've copied the default value from [the Exim 4.80 documentation](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-4.80/doc/html/spec_html/ch-main_configuration.html#SECTalomo), removing the line that inserts the version number.

Comment: thank you very much.
But I'm wondering, which file is to be edited to make this effective could you please guide.

Comment: It depends how Exim is installed on your system.  I'm not familiar with FreeBSD, but try `/etc/exim.conf`, or a file in `/usr/local/etc/exim/configure`.  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: No need to sorry, thank you very much for your nice help -)

I WILL manage somehow.